# Track all rewards issued to a Monero mining pool

Tags: mining-pools, block-reward

I am a newbie, running a test pool on Monero mainnet. At 15k hash rate, it yielded a block in approximately 48 hours. Now the pool is running at an average 50k hash rate and has generated no blocks in span of 10 days. I am unable to spot any problem in daemon logs or any APIs. 
I am using [nodejs-pool](https://github.com/Snipa22/nodejs-pool). Current block maturity is 5.

1. Is there a way to track blocks generated by a pool?
2. What are the possible explanations of such behavior?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Is there a way to track blocks generated by a pool?

The pool implementation you are using includes an API endpoint which reports blocks mined. It's registered at `/api/pool/blocks` by default. E.g. https://supportxmr.com/api/pool/blocks

> 2. What are the possible explanations of such behavior?

At 15 kh/s, finding a block in 48 hours at current network hashrate is just good luck. With 50 kh/s on current network hashrate (~300 mh/s) you're expecting to mine a block in 8 days. Ref: `300000000/50000*120/(24*60*60)`. Note this is no guarantee, luck plays a part still, so 10 days should not be unexpected.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's most appropriate explanation so far.